# Are these partial sums and partial products absolutely convergent?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, mobius-function

For arbitrary $m \in \mathbb{N},$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\ \sum_{d | \#_n}\mu(d)=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\big | \sum_{d | \#_n}\mu(d)\ \big |\ = \ 0,$$
$$\prod_{n=1}^{m}\ \prod_{d | \#_n}d^{\mu(d)}=\prod_{n=1}^{m}\big | \prod_{d | \#_n}d^{\mu(d)} \big |\ = \ 1,$$
where $\#_n:=\prod_{i=1}^n p_i$.

Are these partial sums and partial products absolutely convergent?

Comment: If you're asking about the infinite sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg( \sum_{d \mid \#_n}\mu(d) \bigg)$$ and the infinite product $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg( \prod_{d \mid \#_n}d^{\mu(d)} \bigg),$$ then yes, they are absolutely convergent and their values are $0$ and $1$, respectively, by your computations.

Comment: @GregMartin, should I have placed parentheses as you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about the infinite sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg( \sum_{d\mid\#_n} \mu(d) \bigg)
$$
and the infinite product
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \bigg( \prod_{d\mid\#_n} d^{\mu(d)} \bigg),
$$
then yes, they are absolutely convergent and their values are $0$ and $1$, respectively, by your computations.

I put parentheses around the inner terms to emphasize that this answer is true only when the expressions are interpreted in this (natural) way. For example, the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{d\mid\#_n} |\mu(d)|
$$
certainly does not converge; and the double product
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{d\mid\#_n} d^{\mu(d)}
$$
cannot have its terms arbitrarily rearranged and still converge.